# Kattis Problem Help - Combination Lock (Wrong answer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function

[Combination Lock Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/combinationlock)

I've been working through this question and I just cannot simply find what's wrong with my code. To solve the problem, one is prompted to find the total degree of rotation when opening a combination pad lock. The user input is simple enough: four numbers giving the starting position, then the three numbers of the lock solution.

I've found that the simplest way of solving this question is to covert each number into degrees: 1 being 9 deg and 40 being 360 deg (there are 40 notches total). I've also converted 0 to 40 to create a number line 1 -> 40 : things just seemed to work easier this way.

I've tried various end cases with my current solution - and even referenced my code amongst other online solutions that are acceptable. I can't seem to find the test case that is breaking my code.

Here is what I've got (it's written in Python 3 - I am a beginner) :

```py
def main():
    userInput = [int(z) for z in input().split()]

    for i in range(len(userInput)):
        if userInput[i] == 0:
            userInput[i] = 40

    postiton = userInput[0]
    one = userInput[1]
    two = userInput[2]
    three = userInput[3]
    total = 720

    if postiton == one:
        total += 0
    elif postiton > one:
        total += (postiton - one) * 9
    else:
        total += (40 - (one - postiton)) * 9

    total += 360

    if two == one:
        total += 0
    elif two > one:
        total += (two - one) * 9
    else:
        total += (40 - (one - two)) * 9

    if two == three:
        total += 0
    elif two > three:
        total += (two - three) * 9
    else:
        total += (40 - (three - two)) * 9

    print(total)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Not too sure where to go from here - any help or advise on solving these types of questions would be helpful.

Comment: Try adding `print()` statements after applying each turn (i.e. after each if-elif-else block) and making sure the results agree with what you expect. Keep track of whether you're turning "forward" or "backward" and whether the sign's appropriate. You may also find debugging value in tracking the amount of each turn separately, and only summing them at the end.

Comment: Make sure your code is properly indented. It doesn't look ok according to the `def main()` line followed by no indentation

Comment: First of all, skip degrees and multiply your result by 9 at the very end. But I'm confused by the expected output which seems wrong relative to the problem spec. It says two full turns, then keep going until you hit the first number. Then counter-clockwise one full turn, then keep going until you hit the second number. Then forward to the third. For the first two sample cases, this seems like it should be `(80+30+40+30+30)*9 = 1890`, middle two `(80+20+40+20+20)*9 = 1620` (OK), and for the last two, `(80+10+40+10+10)*9 = 1350`. I don't see how the description should be interpreted otherwise.

Comment: [In the solutions I've seen out there](https://github.com/w-cow-103/Kattis/blob/master/combinationLock.java#L36), it seems like people take whatever the shortest route is to get from one number to the next even if you rotate in the wrong direction, which seems illegal. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lh7tFajBBWY) where you have to continue in the current direction, even if it's longer. For example, on sample input 1, we have to go from 0 to 30 clockwise = 30 ticks, not 10 which is a counterclockwise move. Not the greatest problem IMO, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: honestly it's just a super janky problem - some of the test cases wouldn't even work on a real lock. The description is also just bad, to get the correct answer you have to do a lot of trial interpretations. Not one worth really doing.

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment about actually having problems generating the correct degree values.  With that I took your code and did some tweaks.  Looking at the link for the exercise, I refined the code to again consider combination lock values from 0 -39.  In reviewing your code I think the two things tripping you up were how to compare one position to the next when going counterclockwise versus clockwise and how to treat the net position comparisons in relation to turning the lock clockwise versus counterclockwise.

With that I offer up the following code snippet with a bunch of comments and print statements to track the progress of turning the dial.

```
def main():

    print('Enter four distinct numbers: ')

    userInput = [int(z) for z in input().split()]
    
    print('User entered: ', userInput)

    position = userInput[0]
    one = userInput[1]
    two = userInput[2]
    three = userInput[3]   
    
    # Start with two full turns clockwise.
    
    total = 720
    
    print('Initial two turns: ', total)
    
    # Turn clockwise until at the first number

    if (position == one):
        total+=0

    elif(position > one):
        total += ((position - one) * 9)     # Just a short distance to go clockwise

    else:
        total += ((40 + position - one) * 9)    # Have to go to 0, then on to position one
        
    print('Position one: ', total)

    # Turn counterclockwise one full turn

    total += 360
    
    print('Counterclockwise one turn: ', total)

    if (two == one):
        total+=0

    elif (two < one):           # Two is less than one - need to go around back to zero and then to two
        total += (40 - one + two) * 9

    else:
        total += ((two - one) * 9)  # Short distance to go counterclockwise
        
    print('Position two: ', total)

    if (two == three):
        total+=0

    elif (two > three):         # Two is greater than three - short distance to go clockwise
        total+= (three - two) * 9

    else:
        total+=(40 + two - three) * 9   # Continue to position 0, then on to the position #3

    print('After final position: ',total)
    
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

I tested this out with a simple set of values (0, 20, 10, 30) and everything seemed to add up when I compared to manually tallying the degree totals.  Anyway, give that a go.

Regards.

Comment: "Notice the underscores": they are in the asker's post, but since they didn't format it as code, it was interpreted as markdown formatting.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks for the tip.  I did not catch that the bold bit was formatting.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi NoDakker, thanks for getting back to me me so quickly. Unfortunately, the main function formatting was not the problem. I just translated the code wrongly on stack overflow - I decided just to get rid of the main function entirely to simplify things. My answer is still considered wrong. Any other suggestions or help?

Comment: Hi.  Noting your actual problem, I went back to the drawing board.  See if my revised answer helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I belive this answer should work!